# Calculating VkImageAspectFlagsBits from VkImageCreateInfo?

Tags: vulkan

Under Appendix H of the Vulkan spec it says:

> Aspect (Image):
>
> An image may contain multiple kinds, or aspects, of data for each pixel, where each aspect is
> used in a particular way by the pipeline and may be stored differently or separately from other
> aspects. For example, the color components of an image format make up the color aspect of the
> image, and may be used as a framebuffer color attachment. Some operations, like depth testing,
> operate only on specific aspects of an image. Others operations, like image/buffer copies, only
> operate on one aspect at a time.

In addition there is the type `VkImageAspectFlagBits` which (I think) lists the 7 possible aspects an image can have:

```
VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT
VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT
VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_STENCIL_BIT
VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_METADATA_BIT
VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_0_BIT
VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_1_BIT
VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_2_BIT
```

`VkImageCreateInfo` does not have an aspects field.

If I understand correctly, a given `VkImage` has a subset of these 7 aspects, right?

Is there a way to deduce which of the 7 aspects a VkImage has from its `VkImageCreateInfo`?

ie how would you write a function that returns a bit mask of which aspects an image has?

```
VkImageAspectFlagsBits GetImageAspects(const VkImageCreateInfo& info) { ??? }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mostly derive which aspects an image has from its format:

- `VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT` refers to all R, G, B, and/or A components available in the format.
- `VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT` refers to D components.
- `VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_STENCIL_BIT` refers to S components.
- `VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_n_BIT` refer to the planes of multi-planar formats, i.e. ones with `2PLANE` or `3PLANE` in their name. These aspects are mostly used in copy commands, but can also be used to create a `VkImageView` of an individual plane rather than the whole image.
- `VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_METADATA_BIT` is the odd one whose presence isn't based on format. Instead, images with *sparse residency* (`VK_IMAGE_CREATE_SPARSE_RESIDENCY_BIT`) have a metadata aspect.

If an image doesn't have the components or flag corresponding to the aspect, then it doesn't have that aspect.